# Upgrading to maven 3 from maven 2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have upgraded from Maven 2 to Maven 3 and it seems to be working fine to `clean install`.

However, in the [Maven 3.x Compatibility Notes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+3.x+Compatibility+Notes), it is mentioned that the `<reporting>` tag is no longer supported and **should be moved** up to the `<build>` tag.

---

```
<reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <reportSets>
          <reportSet>
            <reports>
              <report>dependencies</report>
              <report>dependency-convergence</report>
              <report>dependency-management</report>
              <report>index</report>
              <report>plugin-management</report>
              <report>project-team</report>
              <report>license</report>
              <report>summary</report>
            </reports>
          </reportSet>
        </reportSets>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

---

I **have** commented this out and moved the plugin tag and its content, to the `<build><plugins>` tag.

When I run `mvn validate` now, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com.company.projectName:ProjectName:1.2 (C:\Svn\projectName\branches\projectName-1.2\System\4_ImplementationSet\WAS\src\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Malformed POM C:\Svn\projectName\branches\projectName-1.2\System\4_ImplementationSet\WAS\src\pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'reportSets' (position: START_TAG seen ...</version>\r\n        <reportSets>... @123:21)  @ C:\Svn\projectName\branches\projectName-1.2\System\4_ImplementationSet\WAS\src\pom.xml, line 123, column 21 -> [Help 2]
```

Am I missing something? I could just leave things as they are, but I gave it a try to move it, but it did not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
    <plugins>
       ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <reportPlugins> 
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <reportSets>
                                <reportSet>
                                    <reports>
                                        <report>dependencies</report>
                                        <report>dependency-convergence</report>
                                        <report>dependency-management</report>
                                        <report>index</report>
                                        <report>plugin-management</report>
                                        <report>project-team</report>
                                        <report>license</report>
                                        <report>summary</report>
                                    </reports>
                                </reportSet>
                            </reportSets>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    ...
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ...
    </plugins>
```

(untested; I'm not sure about the reportSets-part)

Comment: Thanks! That worked ( changed from 2.4 to 2.1 ). At least there is no complain from mvn validate :)

Comment: In the meantime you can use version 3.1 of maven-site-plugin. Furthermore the doc about upgrade http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html

Comment: why i'm  getting this exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sonatype/aether/graph/Dependency ... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonatype.aether.graph.Dependency ... ?

Answer (score 3):

It is not simply a matter of copying the tag to a different place.  The schema has changed in other ways too.

I suggest that you read the documentation for "Maven 3 only" configuration, since that's what you seem to be trying to do.  Here's a [link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/maven-3.html#New_Configuration_Maven_3_only_no_reports_configuration_inheritance).