# How to get MavenProject in maven3

Tags: java, maven-3

I want to automate part of our build system in Java. For that I need to calculate a dependency tree of the sources that are existent in a given file tree.

So, I want to crawl over a set of directories and find the `pom.xml` files that are existent there. That works fine. Then I want to parse that files to instances of `MavenProject` so I can call `getParent()` and `getDependencies()` and such on it.

So, the question is: how do I get a fully populated `MavenProject` with maven3 libraries? Its is acceptable for me to include a third party library if necessary but would prefer a solution that consists of maven natives.

I have read [Get MavenProject from just the POM.xml - pom parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4381460/get-mavenproject-from-just-the-pom-xml-pom-parser) but the answers there don't work for me (the `MavenProject` is not not populated correctly)

My code is in Java, so I want to have the contents of a method like this:

```
private MavenProject makeProjectFromPom(File pomXML) {
    // Here is what I don't know.
}
```

So that I can do something like this in my program:

```
public List<MavenProject> getAllMavenProjectsWithParent(File rootDir, MavenProject parent) {
   List<File> allPoms = findAllPoms(rootDir);
   List<MavenProject> result = new ArrayList<>();
   for(File nextPom : allPoms) {
       MavenProject next = makeProjectFromPom(nextPom);
       if(next.hasParent() && next.getParent().equals(parent))
           result.add(next);
   }
   return result;
}
```

This is just an example, but one that does not work at the moment for me.

In Maven2 I could do it like this:

```
    String basePath = "somepath";
    MavenEmbedder embedder = new MavenEmbedder();
    File basedir = new File(basePath);
    final List<File> allDirsWithPomXML = new ArrayList<>();
    // the next line crawls through the directory and collects references to pom.xml paths.
    gatherPomXMLPaths(basedir, allDirsWithPomXML);
    embedder.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    embedder.start();
    List<MavenProject> collectedProjects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (File nextDir : allDirsWithPomXML) {
        collectedProjects.addAll(embedder.collectProjects(nextDir, new String[]{"pom.xml"}, new String[0]));
    }
```

The `MavenProject` references in the `collectedProjects` would now contain information like parent, dependencies etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10413676/3377857 is it that what yo uare looking for?

Comment: Is the command `mvn dependency:tree` useful?

Comment: @Stewart No. I don't want to parse a text output for something that the API should provide. I mean, I could copy the contents of MavenCli or use reflection and build the state myself that MavenCli has hidden in its private methods, but I would rather not.

Comment: I meant use it as a model to build your own plugin. It's not so difficult.

Comment: @Stewart Yes, I know, but I'd rather not. In Mvn2 that function was build in and I could do this in 3 lines. I expected that this is there in Mvn3 as well.